# Sticking image to bottom of view?

Tags: android, user-interface, adobe-xd

I have designed a splash screen in Adobe XD as shown:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSVNj.jpg)

Now when I exported the parts of the image to android studio, I was unable to make all the images stick to the bottom as in XD. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYUwU.jpg)

Can someone tell me how I would go about doing that and would be the best ViewGroup for such task?

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/group_1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show me your layout file.

Comment: share your xml.

Comment: There it is. I exported all the parts from the first image as a single item

Comment: Meaning you want your image to cover the full width and height of your splash screen?

Comment: Not the entire screen but rather like it is in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSVNj.jpg

Comment: OK. So you want that Cairo OBGYN 2020 image at the center both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: Yes and the orange curves to surround it from the bottom, without any of the background showing. Basically stick the whole thing to the bottom.

Comment: I see. In any case, you've already been provided with an answer. If it were me, I'd use multiple images then position them on the screen with a `ConstraintLayout`, and those images wouldn't be raster but SVG files. Have you understood all that?

Comment: Yes I did. Thank you for explaining and being patient with a beginner like me. I will try to do that soon

Comment: Very good. So try with that CAIRO OBGYN 2020 as one separate image, the logos below it as another image, then the orange curves as a third image. Position them on the screen the way you want, and once they're in place, you'll be able to apply your fade animations to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with either `ViewGroup`. But the problem is not the the view group - the problem is that you have a single image for the whole content - it is bad practice.

There should be at least 2 images - one for the background and the other is for the content.

It is due to fragmentation issue regarding device screens - there too many different resolution, aspect ratios and dpis to make the single image work properly on them all.

I will show you an example based on your UI with a background and logo image with small images below logo. You just need to separate it into two files - background could be jpg but logo must be png with transparency. In case you will do it - here is how your layout should look like.

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</FrameLayout>
```

You may want to experiment with `android:padding` and `android:scaleType` to achieve the best result.

### Edit

Changed `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` - it will work better this way

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand it is bad practice but I did it this way because I wanted the background to have a gradient then later I would put a fade in animation on the rest (the curves and logos). I don't know if it is doable or not so I will try your solution ASAP. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Primatron it is doable only if all the animated elements are separate images in separate image view. Of course you can also animate a single image in plenty of ways but it is much harder to do and it will require quite a long learning curve.

Comment: @Primatron check out my edit for logo ```ImageView```